# In Android, how to check programatically which secure element settings is selected in NFC Advanced Settings (SIM or eSE or HCE)?

Tags: android, nfc

In Android, how to check programatically which secure element settings is selected in NFC Advanced Settings (SIM or eSE or HCE) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the user to change it you can make it programmatically using this piece of code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String mPackage = "com.android.settings";
String mClass = ".nfc.NfcAdvancedRoutingSetting";
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mPackage+mClass));
startActivity(intent);
```

I'm still searching for a way to check which one is activated.

Comment: Have you found a way to check which one is selected?

Comment: Have you found a way to check - is there a possibility with the Android SDK to check the NFC "Secure Element" location currently set on the device? For example "Auto, Android OS, SIM"

Answer (score 0):

One of the Android documentation have is,

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#EXTRA_SECURE_ELEMENT_NAME

looks like its possible to get Secure Element name.