# how to check NFC Secure element location

Tags: nfc

Is there a possibility with the Android SDK to check the NFC "Secure Element" location currently set on the device? For example "Auto, Android OS, SIM"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758539/in-android-how-to-check-programatically-which-secure-element-settings-is-select/29564762#29564762

I referred this link - but sill dont know how to identify which location is set.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found some Android documentation,

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#EXTRA_SECURE_ELEMENT_NAME

looks like its possible to get Secure Element name.

Comment: this doesn't work, the app doesn't get the TRANSACTION_DETECTED broadcast at all.